# Python JPEG file carver takes incredibly long on small dumps

Tags: python

I'm writing a JPEG file carver as a part of a forensic lab.

The assignment is to write a script that can extract JPEG files from a 10 MB dd-dump. We are not permitted to assign the file to a memory variable (because if it were to be too big, it would cause an overflow), but instead, the Python script should read directly from the file.

My script seems to work perfectly fine, but it takes extremely long to finish (upwards 30-40 minutes). Is this an expected behavior? Even for such a small 10 MB file? Is there anything I can do to shorten the time?

This is my code:

```
# Extract JPEGs from a file.
import sys
with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as binary_file:
    binary_file.seek(0, 2)  # Seek the end
    num_bytes = binary_file.tell()  # Get the file size

    count = 0 # Our counter of which file we are currently extracting.
    for i in range(num_bytes):
        binary_file.seek(i)
        four_bytes = binary_file.read(4)    
        whole_file = binary_file.read()

        if four_bytes == b"\xff\xd8\xff\xd8" or four_bytes == b"\xff\xd8\xff\xe0" or four_bytes == b"\xff\xd8\xff\xe1":  # JPEG signature

            whole_file = whole_file.split(four_bytes)

            for photo in whole_file:
                count += 1
                name = "Pic " + str(count) + ".jpg"
                file(name, "wb").write(four_bytes+photo)
                print name
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aren't you reading your whole file on every for loop?

E: What I mean, is at every byte you read your whole file (for a 10MB file you are reading 10MB 10 million times, aren't you?), even if the four bytes didn't match up to JPEG signature.

E3 : What you need is on every byte to check if there is file to be written (checking for the header/signature). If you match the signature, you have to start writing bytes to file, but first, since you already read 4 bytes, you have to jump back where you are. Then, when reading the byte and writing it to file, you have to check for JPEG ending. If the file ends, you have to write the next byte and close the stream and start searching for header again. This will not extract a JPEG from inside another JPEG.

```
import sys
with open("C:\\Users\\rauno\\Downloads\\8-jpeg-search\\8-jpeg-search.dd", "rb") as binary_file:
    binary_file.seek(0, 2)  # Seek the end
    num_bytes = binary_file.tell()  # Get the file size
    write_to_file = False
    count = 0 # Our counter of which file we are currently extracting.

    for i in range(num_bytes):
        binary_file.seek(i)

        if write_to_file is False:                
            four_bytes = binary_file.read(4)
            if four_bytes == b"\xff\xd8\xff\xd8" or four_bytes == b"\xff\xd8\xff\xe0" or four_bytes == b"\xff\xd8\xff\xe1":  # JPEG signature
                write_to_file = True
                count += 1
                name = "Pic " + str(count) + ".jpg"
                f = open(name,"wb")
                binary_file.seek(i)


        if write_to_file is True: #not 'else' or you miss the first byte
            this_byte = binary_file.read(1)
            f.write(this_byte)
            next_byte = binary_file.read(1) # assuming it does read next byte - i think "read" jumps the seeker (which is why you have .seek(i) at the beginning)
            if this_byte == b"\xff" and next_byte==b"\xd9" :
                f.write(next_byte)
                f.close()
                write_to_file = False
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. However, if I move it out of the for-loop (e.g. after the `num_bytes = binary_file.tell()` at the beginning, I get an error saying:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Final.py", line 16, in <module>
    whole_file = whole_file.split(four_bytes)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: Edited my answer, 'cause I didn't know I can comment too :)

Comment: Seems to have worked much faster, however, now I get duplicate images for some reason. I think it's in the if-statement?

Comment: I believe it's to do with how whole file is being split and that you iterate over it.
However "We are not permitted to assign the file to a memory variable" -- isn't that exactly what you are doing with "whole_file"?

Comment: Hm, you're probably right. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: I don't know nothing about jpeg files or the task you have at hand or the binary file you are going through. Could you tell me more about the file you are going through?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163235/discussion-between-phairero-and-tobulos1).